# Python list of lists remove single quotes on one value

Tags: python, string, list, unpivot

I have a list of fields an am trying to create an unpivot expression with stack() in pyspark.

stack() requires the params: number, field name, then **field value**.
`stack(30, 'field1', field1...)`

I have a list of lists like

```
[['field1','field1'],['field2','field2']...]
```

I then can make a single list

```
['field1','field1','field2','field2']
```

But i need to remove the single quotes from the second occurence, so it works as the **"field value"**

```
unpivot_Expr = "stack(30, 'field1',field1,'field2',field2...)"
```

So far i'm getting `stack(30, 'field1','field1','field2','field2'...)`
I'm not sure how, or which is the easiest place to remove the single quotes?  Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:
Sorry should've given context, I need to insert this string into a pyspark select expression

```
unpivot_df = df.select("hashKey", expr(unpivot_Expr))
```

Currently I drop the list into the string and replace the [] like this

```
unpivot_Expr = "stack({0}, {1})".format(str(len(fieldList)), str(fieldList).replace("[","").replace("]",""))
```

Comment: By removing quotes your "convert" strings to actual fields.

Comment: do you mean you need to get the value of a variable named `field1` ?

Comment: or do you mean cast a string like `"123"` to some other type, say and integer?

Comment: I made some edits, hope that makes sense, unpivot_Expr is a big string, that I'm using in the expr() function.  Just need to remove that 2nd fields single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about building up the string `unpivot_Expr` piece by piece via:

```py
all_fields = [
    ['field1','field1'],
    ['field2','field2']
]

unpivot_Expr = "stack(30"
for pair in all_fields:
    unpivot_Expr  += f", '{pair[0]}', {pair[1]}"
unpivot_Expr += ")"

print(unpivot_Expr)
```

I think that will give you the tring you seek:

```
stack(30, 'field1', field1, 'field2', field2)
```